# Цветной вывод в Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Есть массив

```
field_game = np.full((15, 15), '*', dtype=str)
```

Можно ли поменять цвет элемента по координатам?

Допустим мне надо чтобы при выводе элемент с координатами (5, 5) был жёлтым.
Пробовал через colorama, не вышло. Место элемента "*" подставилось вот это "\x1b"

Comment: В кавычках стоит звёздочка

Comment: Для чего это вам? Хотите сделать консольную игру?

Comment: Именно так и хочу

Comment: знаю как сделать такое в Pandas и не для консоли, а для Jupyter... Как сделать для консоли не знаю...

Comment: Срезай поле и сделай новый массив для вывода на экран